# Codeigniter ci-merchant library - authorize.net payment gateway integration issue

Tags: payment-gateway, codeigniter

I tried to integrate codeigniter authorize.net payment gateway by using the docs http://ci-merchant.org , I can successfully integrate the paypal but unfortunately i couldn't do authorize.net. The below code i have tried,but not working, how to do it ?

```
$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('authorize_net_sim');
$settings = array(
'api_login_id' => 'xxxx',
'transaction_key' => 'xxxx',
'test_mode' => true);

$this->merchant->initialize($settings);

$params = array( 
        'amount' => 10, 
        'currency' => 'USD', 
        'card_no' => '4111111111111111', 
        'exp_month' => '12', 
        'exp_year' => '14', 
        'csc' => 123, 
        'first_name' => 'Ashok', 
        'last_name' => 'KS',
        'return_url' => 'http://www.ioss.in/success',
        'cancel_url' => 'http://www.ioss.in/cancel'    
        );
$response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);
```

`print_r($response)` returns:

```
Merchant_response Object (
    [_status:protected] => failed
    [_message:protected] =>
    [_reference:protected] =>
    [_data:protected] =>
    [_redirect_url:protected] =>
    [_redirect_method:protected] => GET
    [_redirect_message:protected] =>
    [_redirect_data:protected] =>
)
```

UPDATE 1 
after change the code, its working fine...

```
$params = array(
'amount' => 10.00,
'currency' => 'USD',
'return_url' => 'http://www.ioss.in',
'cancel_url' => 'http://www.google.in');
```

Comment: And what does `print_r($response)` return?

Comment: Merchant_response Object
(
    [_status:protected] => failed
    [_message:protected] => 
    [_reference:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => 
    [_redirect_url:protected] => 
    [_redirect_method:protected] => GET
    [_redirect_message:protected] => 
    [_redirect_data:protected] => 
)

Comment: Hmm. Two things: Authorize.net SIM doesn't need a credit card number. I think you want Authorize.net AIM. Also, when I've seen a failure with no error message before it was because you aren't using HTTPS on your payment page (which is required to securely transmit credit card details).

Comment: Thankyou, when I change code         $params = array(
    'amount' => 10.00,
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'return_url' => 'http://www.ioss.in',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://www.ioss.in'); then works but it shows the error The following errors have occurred.

(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.
Can I use test account for checking ?? because it goes to https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Comment: Ah good. I think you want to set the `developer_mode` parameter to `true` instead of `test_mode` - I can't exactly remember the difference, it's something weird that Auth.net does, and there are two different ways of testing (either using a developer account, or as a test transaction on a live account).

Comment: Yes its correct, when make the developer_mode true its working fine,  i completely reviewed the whole code for finding the answer....

Comment: @JohnConde I flagged this to migrate to stack overflow, where it is more appropriate. Can you do that instead of closing it outright?

Comment: That's what I did but the system just closed it instead. I'm guessing there's something about it that prevented it from being migrated.

Comment: Ok, strange. Oh well, it's solved now anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: After successful payment the control goes to return_url, but the problem is the current session goes out, we cannot get the values!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, if the `$response` is failing with no error message it's generally because you are trying to submit credit card details unencrypted (not using HTTPS), which isn't supported by CI Merchant (for obvious security reasons).

In this case, the credit card details wern't necessary anyway because the Auth.net SIM gateway is an off-site gateway (card details are not entered on your site). Changing the $request to this fixed the problem:

```
$params = array(
    'amount' => 10.00,
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'return_url' => 'http://www.ioss.in',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://www.google.in',
);
```

In addition, to use the Authorize.net developer endpoint, `developer_mode` must be set to `true` in the gateway settings. This is different from `test_mode` (Auth.net specific feature):

```
$settings = array(
    'api_login_id' => 'xxxx',
    'transaction_key' => 'xxxx',
    'developer_mode' => true,
);
$this->merchant->initialize($settings);
```

Comment: How to know the payment is success,  I cannot use the function $response->success() ?? Can we use normal post method to check ?

Comment: You need to call `purchase_return()` when the customer returns to your site, as per the tutorial on http://ci-merchant.org/